# What's the equivalent of `swapExactETHForTokens` in Uniswap V3?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

In Uniswap V2 router, there's this `swapExactETHForTokens` to swap ETH directly to other token.

I didn't find similar function in V3 router. Does this mean this is not supported anymore? Thanks!